# How to return subscribed data from a function in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a function and the function has multiple API calls using for loops. I want to concatenate all the responses that are subscribed and return it when the last API call's data is subscribed.

I am able to get the combined data inside the function but the return value is getting undefined from where it was called. I am calling this function for mapping the response. These all are part of my service not any component. I can not change the structure so even if it is not the right way to do it is there any workable solution? I am new to angular 2.

```
call()
{
    http.get(url)                                                            
        .map((res) => this.doll(res)) /*here the function returning undefined */
        .subscribe(/*something*/);
}
doll(res) : Observable /*type*/
{                                                                           
   for(looping through this APIs)                                                
   {                                                                               
   http.get(url)                                                              
       .map((res) => res)                                                   
       .subscribe((data: any) =>{                                         
           /*concatenate response */                                           
           if(certain condition)                                             
           {                                                               
               /*getting all the data together */                                
               console.log(data); /*working fine and getting the desired data*/    
               return data;                                                   
           }                                                        
       });                                                               
   }                                                                               
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is that you use async/await to await for the http calls to complete. This will make your code easier to read and will possibly be easier to achieve what you want. Using rxjs operators to combine the Observables may also be an idea.

Comment: I am getting all the correct data from the calls , and inside the if condition i m able to get the combined data of all the calls. The problem is when I am trying to return the combined data from the if block , it is getting undefined from where it is called. Requesting you to give some example on this .

Comment: Yours doll function is actually not returning anything, and if it is supposed to return an observable, you would also need to subscribe to it to get the values. As I mentioned on my previous comment, async/await could help you simplify your code. There are plenty of examples on how to use it across SO and the entire web.

Comment: @tirtha do you still need help with this question?

Comment: Yes please ! Some code block would be great .

Answer (score 0):

Tirtha, you must use forkJoin, to get an Unique observable. Then you can subscribe to the observable. Generally you use a service -that manage the calls- and a component, that subscribe to the service

```
//your service
doll() : Observable<any[]> //return an array of anys
{      
   //I supouse you has in APIS some like
   APIS=[this.http.get("url1"),this.http.get("url2"),this.http.get("url3")...]
   return forkJoin(APIS);                                                                   
}


//So, In a component (if you inject hte service), you can subscribe to "doll"
this.myService.doll().subscribe(res=>{
    console.log(res[0]) //the response to http.get("url1")
    console.log(res[1]) //the response to http.get("url2")
})
```